# Any better approach to tackle this simple business use case?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, autofac

I have the following  interface:

```
public interface IValidator
{
    // Checks whether the selected roles are Valid based on Buisness rules for the 
    // specific EntityValidator
    bool HasCompleteValidSelection(
        ICollection<Role> availableRoles, ICollection<Role> selectedRoles);        
    //Checks whether the available roles are Valid for the specific entity 
    bool HasValidRoles(ICollection<Role> availableRolesList);
    //Computes the Remaining Roles that needs to be selected to make it a Valid selection
    ICollection<Role> GetRemainingRoles(
        ICollection<Role> availableRoles, ICollection<Role> selectedRoles);
}
```

Now, I have bunch of EntityTypes,mentioned in the enum:

```
public enum EntityType
{        
    Shop= 1,
    SmallBuisness= 2,
    Corporation = 3,
    Firm = 4,
    Partnership = 5,
    Unknown = 0
}
```

All the above Entity Types have their corresponding validator classes which implements the IValidator.

```
public class ShopValidator : IValidator
{
    public bool HasCompleteValidSelection(
        ICollection<Role> availableRoles, ICollection<Role> selectedRoles)
    { /*implementation */ }
    public bool HasValidRoles(ICollection<Role> availableRolesList)
    { /*implementation */ }
    public ICollection<Role> GetRemainingRoles(
        ICollection<Role> availableRoles, ICollection<Role> selectedRoles)
    { /*implementation */ }
}
```

But the concern is some of the validator classes are having exact same logic/code.
What I have thought of is:

1. Instead of Interface, created abstract class and kept the common
   code there
2. Validator classes, which has different implementation,are
   overriding the abstract class.

Now, my questions are:

1. Although the above is working fine, is there any better
   approach/design pattern more suitable for the above scenario?
2. I am using Autofac like below, its working fine, but is there any
   issue that you can foresee?

   builder.RegisterType().As().Keyed(EntityType.Shop);

   // other validators similarly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I like your initial proposal. Some will probably disagree, but I like the symmetry of creating a class for each entity type, even if some of those classes have no code.

That is, if there is some common code, I would use your suggestion of converting the interface to a base class and put your common code there. (Much like CException.)

Of course, if the common code is more complex, then you might have more specialized base classes that your final class can derive from, but in that case it isn't near as elegant.